# Least number of factors $\sigma(p^e)$ of representation of $\sigma(N)$ to get the least multiple of $\operatorname{rad}(N)$, for odd perfect numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, divisors-multiples, perfect-numbers

I've cross-posted this from the post of Mathematics Stack Exchange that I've asked (Apr, 2nd 2020) with title [*On the least number of factors* $\sigma(q^{e_q})$ *to get the least multiple of* $\operatorname{rad}(n)$, *on assumption that* $n$ *is an odd perfect number*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3606189/on-the-least-number-of-factors-sigmaqe-q-to-get-the-least-multiple-of) and identificator MSE **3606189.**

**Definitions and notation.** We denote the sum of divisors function $\sum_{1\leq d\mid m}d$ as $\sigma(m)$ and the radical of an integer $m>1$ as $\operatorname{rad}(m)$, the product of distinct primes dividing $m$ with the definition $\operatorname{rad}(1)=1$. Both arithmetic functions are multiplicative functions. The number of distinct prime factors dividing an integer $m>1$ has the notation of the prime omega function $\omega(m)$.

For integers $m>1$ since the sum of divisors function $\sigma(m)$ is multiplicative, and we know that the fundamental theorem of arithmetic provide us the representation $m=\prod_{q\mid m}q^{e_q}$ ($q$ are the distinct primes dividing $m$ and $e_q$ their corresponding exponents in this unique factorization: $m$ can be represented as product of those prime powers $q^{e_q}$ and the representation is unique, see [2]) we get that $\sigma(m)$ has the representation $\prod_{q\mid m}\sigma(q^{e_q})$ (see [1]).

**Claim.** *It is obvious invoking Euclid–Euler theorem for even perfect numbers that if* $n$ *is an even perfect number, there exist* **two factors** *of the form* $\sigma(q^{e_q})$ *from the representation* $\sigma(n)=\prod_{q\mid m}\sigma(q^{e_q})$ *such that their product is a multiple of* $\operatorname{rad}(n)$.

Here again we emphasize that $\sigma(q^{e_q})$ represents those generic factors in the previous representation of $\sigma(m)$. For even perfect numbers $n$ we've that $\omega(n)=2$, and the claim tell us that we need to multiply both factors, that is $\sigma(2^{p-1})\sigma(2^p-1)$ to get the least multiple of $\operatorname{rad}(n)$.

**Summary and goal.** Thus for even perfect numbers $n$ we need $$\kappa:=2$$ factors from the representation $\prod_{q\mid n}\sigma(q^{e_q})$ of $\sigma(n)$ to get the least multiple of $\operatorname{rad}(n)=2(2^p-1)$, being $\kappa$ the least possible choice of this number $1\leq \kappa\leq\omega(n)=2$. I would like to know if it is feasible a similar discussion on assumption that $N$ is an odd perfect number, that is if we can get an approximation or some reasoning about what about the $1\leq \kappa\leq \omega(N)$.

> **Question.**  I would like to know, on assumption that $N$ is an odd perfect number, if it is possible to do some work or deduction* about the least number $\kappa$, with $1\leq\kappa\leq \omega(N)$, of those factors of the form $\sigma(q^{e_q})$ that I need to multiply to get the least multiple of $\operatorname{rad}(N)$. **Many thanks.**

*I mean a work or deduction about an approximation of the value of the quantity $\kappa$ for odd perfect numbers.

Here $N=\prod_{q\mid N}q^{e_q}$ is the canonical representation ([2]) of our odd perfect number $N$, compare if you need it with Euler's theorem for odd perfect number. In the linked post were added valuable comments and references.

### References:

[1] Tom M. Apostol, *Introduction to analytic number theory*, Undergraduate Texts in Mathematics, New York-Heidelberg: Springer-Verlag (1976).

[2] Wikipedia has the articles [*Fundamental theorem of arithmetic*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic#Canonical_representation_of_a_positive_integer) and [*Perfect number.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number)

Comment: Please feel free to add your feedback in comments or as an answer (I've cross-posted it since I think that can be an interesting post and that maybe it is possible to do some work on MathOverflow about the question). As reference for all users Wikipedia has also the articles with titles *Prime omega function*, *Radical of an integer* and *Euclid–Euler theorem*. Many thanks and good day.